# Can I force HTML attributes to wrap bt eslint

Tags: eslint

error:

```html
 <span class="label" id="span">
    Hello
 </span>
```

Can eslint restrict the specification of HTML?

right:

```html
 <span class="label"
       id="span">
    Hello
 </span>
```